# MarkLogic node.js - is it possible to support a derived value in parseBindings?

Tags: marklogic

We have a search application using MarkLogic node.js. We use parsedQuery like this:

```
            qb.parsedFrom(prop.search, 
            qb.parseBindings(
                qb.word('name', qb.bind('name')),
                qb.word('birthdate', qb.bind('birthdate')),
                qb.range('count', qb.datatype('float'), qb.bind('count'))
            )
        )
```

The above currently supports search syntax like "count GT 50", etc. We would like to support searching using a derived value such as age. That is, we want to support a search syntax like "age GT 10", where the age value is not stored in the documents in the database but rather needs to be computed from the birthdate on the fly. We can't store the age in the documents since the age changes depending on the current date.

Is this possible and if so, how? If it matters, we are using ML8

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The way to do this is with a [custom constraint](http://docs.marklogic.com/guide/search-dev/search-api#id_49750). The parse function constructs a cts query based on the parameters. To support something like "age GT 10", you'd want to build something like

```
cts:element-range-query(
  xs:QName("date-of-birth"), "<=", 
  fn:current-date() - xs:yearMonthDuration("P10Y")
)
```

You'll need a date range index on `date-of-birth`.

Once you've build that custom constraint, you can call it from the MarkLogic Node.js Client API. See [Using a Custom Constraint Parser](http://docs.marklogic.com/guide/node-dev/search#id_68808). There's an [example](http://docs.marklogic.com/guide/node-dev/search#id_77681) in the Node Developer's Guide, too.

Comment: An alternative to Dave's good suggestion is to do the calculation on the criteria in the client.  In the example, if you want to find an age greater than 10, you search for a birth date less than a date 10 years in the past.

Comment: One other footnote -- if you want to filter based on an aggregate such as a count or sum over a group of rows, you can use Optic in MarkLogic 9.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to change that binding in this way:

```
qb.word('birthdate', qb.bind('age'))
```

But I assume you can't change qb.word to qb.value() as the birthdate has a different format than what you'd like to search on (1990-01-01 vs 20 for example). Can you please confirm?

Comment: Yes, that's exactly the issue. The age value is not stored in the document, needs to be derived on the fly (since obviously the age is dependent on the current date). I'll update the question to make this clearer